# Trailing zeroes in a format string?

Tags: ruby

I have figures representing monetary amounts coming in -- `45.10`, `24.35`, `17.99`, and so on.

I want to split these into the dollar and cent portions, do something to the dollars, and then output a string of `dollars + '.' + cents`.

PROBLEM: The figure `.10` obviously becomes `1`, and I don't want to output `$84.1`. I want `$84.10`. So the format string should specify "two-digit integer, with a *trailing* zero if there's only one digit."

Any search I do just turns up results for *leading* zeroes. Is this possible?

Comment: Look at `ljust` [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-ljust)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%d.%02d", dollars, cents) # must be numbers
```